# Can two remote users view the same PHP web page and each update it?

Tags: php

Is it possible for the same web page to be viewed by two different remotely separated web browser such that when input is put into one browser the same data is displayed in the other browser? Think GoogleDocs (I know this works) or perhaps a document in SharePoint (I'm told this works).

Comment: Yes this is possible.
Now please rewrite your question to be more precise in what you want to do exactly.

Comment: It is possible but not with PHP. To know more about it read on (1) https://togetherjs.com/ (2) http://socket.io/

Comment: @Rik_S: I have a bespoke calculator in a web page. The idea is to have a customer able to input data and get a result. The account manager is also viewing the page, at a location other than the customer's, who can adjust the data input and recalculate the result for the customer. The customer's page is now reflecting the update just made by the account manager. This process repeats until both customer and account manager are happy with the result.

Comment: @Everyone: Thank you for the pointers to AJAX, JavaScript and TogetherJS. I will have a go at getting the above scenario implemented and come back with a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`PHP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) is a server-side scripting language, this means that when the client asks to view the page the PHP-script will render an HTML-page that the client then receives. Any changes that are then done on the client-side will not affect the file on the server.

The way of doing this would be (as already suggested by VWGolf2) to use JavaScript and upload the changes to the server once the client has made any changes. These can then be downloaded (using JavaScript) to the other client and then updated on their webpage.

You can ofcourse write this all in PHP, but it will not be the PHP that is performing the actual logic on the client-side, it will most likely be JavaScript.

Comment: VWGolf2 is correct, but Sander's answer is more informative. I will purse this technique in the production version. I've used TogetherJS to build a demonstration and it works very nicely. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can not solve this problem in php. You will need to use JavaScript and ajax.